# Manifest merger failed when adding CameraX gradle dependency

Tags: android, gradle, camera, android-gradle-plugin, android-camerax

I'm trying to use the CameraX library in a brand new Android Studio project based off the official [CameraX demo app](https://github.com/android/camera/tree/master/CameraXBasic):

I've added the following dependencies to my (module) build.gradle:

```
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha01"
```

and my AndroidManifest.xml looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="simplediary.raouf.camerapoc">

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

        <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>
      </manifest>
```

Trying to run the project I get the following error

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.1.0-beta01] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:9:3-23:17 to override.
```

Adding "tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory" to the application element in the manifest now results in this error:

```
Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

So under 'Merged Manifest' in AndroidManifest.xml these are the errors I'm now seeing:

```
Error: tools:replace specified at line:9 for attribute android:appComponentFactory, but no new value specified app main manifest (this file), line 8 Error: Validation failed, exiting app main manifest (this file)
```

How can I get around this issue? Full build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "simplediary.raouf.camerapoc"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.0.0-alpha01"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-alpha01"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: You'll need to migrate to **AndroidX** artifact. check here : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to Migrate to `AndroidX` library:

here's the steps:

> 1/ go under "refactor"
>
> 2/in the drop down menu select "Migrate to AndroidX"
>
> 3/make sure to keep a Backup (by version control or check the keep backup checkbox)
>
> 4/follow the setup wizard
>
> 5/when finished clean project & rebuild

Comment: Under app -> refactor I only see Migrate to AppCompat and Migrate. None of them have any reference to AndroidX and I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @eyesenberg go under `Refactor`

Comment: @eyesenberg If you have any Maven dependencies that have not been migrated to the AndroidX namespace or any other problem while migrating, try to override it manually by going to your `gradle.properties` file and then adding those to lines: `android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true`

Comment: Still the same issue. I can't see AndroidX under Refactor (but did add those gradle properties). My Android Studio hasn't been updated in probably a year however, so updating that now

Comment: @eyesenberg yes, updating AS will definitely fix the issue